# Keep original type for certain fields when using ObjectMapper::convertValue()

Tags: java, postgresql, jackson, jdbctemplate

I want to generate a `Map` object to be passed as argument to a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate::update()` as second parameter from an existing POJO. One property is of type `java.util.UUID`.

```java
@Builder
@Data
static class POJOObject {
  @Builder.Default
  @NonNull
  private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
  @NonNull
  private String data;
}
```

When this object is mapped with object mapper the given property is serialized to a `String` and the database operation fails.

```java
var pojo = POJOObject.builder().data("something").build();
Map<String, Object> mapFromPojo = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(pojo, Map.class);
// this throws an exception 
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO pojo_table ( id, data ) VALUES ( :id, :data )",
    mapFromPojo
);
// this works
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO pojo_table ( id, data ) VALUES ( :id, :data )",
    ImmutableMap.of("id", pojo.getId(), "data", pojo.getData()
);
```

The PostgreSQL table is defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pojo_table (
   id   UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
   data TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Is there a way to use the `ObjectMapper` so that the value's type of the `id` key is `UUID` instead of being serialized into a `String`? Or is there even another/better way to pass the data of `POJOObject` instance to the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate::update()` call without manually adding field by field to a `Map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution, that I completely oversaw before: [PostgreSQL Cast](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/). To make it work, the `SQL` string needs to be modified to cast types and that way all properties of the map can be passed as `String`s.

With the `POJOObject` from above:

```java
var pojo = POJOObject.builder().data("something").build();

// map can be all strings, when using postgreSQL cast on non-TEXT fields  
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO pojo_table ( id, data ) VALUES ( :id::uuid, :data )",
    new ObjectMapper().convertValue(pojo, Map.class)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why the update fails as you have it - you have to specify when passing to the query that it's a UUID type. I think your best bet here is to just manually create the map - that way you don't have any surprises when you add values. But you're right, that's the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, @Nick. The question was if there was a way to use `convertValue` or any other means of avoiding manual mapping.